# Converting 16bit PCM to 32bit PCM

Tags: java, audio, pcm

I have audio data in PCM signed 16 bit mono format but I need to convert this to PCM signed 32 bit mono Format. The data is only available as bytes in Little Endian order. So how can I accomplish to convert the data into 32 bit format? I didn't find anything about this special question. I use Java as programming language.

Comment: Define "data". Is it a file, a stream, raw bytes? The conversion itself is (conceptually) trivial, but wildly different in terms of API/code to implement depending on data representation.

Comment: The data is just raw bytes in the explained audio format most times send from a Smartphone over udp.

Comment: I found a Solution. I simply made a bitwise Left shift by 16bits(Rightshift in little Endian). But when I now import the converted data into Audacity, there are some "peeks". I don't know where they come from. How can I remove these "peeks".

Comment: I tried to do the opposite (32-bit Signed PCM to 16bit-Signed PCM) by **right bits shifting** (yes, it involves data-loss) and also encountered noise from the resampled audio data, I think we both should use a third-party library which supports doing those operations in high quality.